# High Sierra: push notifications are not clickable

Tags: macos, apple-push-notifications, macos-high-sierra

I am experiencing issue with macOS 10.13. 
Push notifications created for my app are not clickable by its content. Action button works the same as on 10.12, but `userNotificationCenter:didActivateNotification:` does not get called with `NSUserNotificationActivationTypeContentsClicked` activation type.

Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Did you learn any more about this? We are seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Yes, it is an Apple issue. I've submitted a radar, it was closed as duplicate. I guess it would be fixed in the nearest future.

Comment: What's the radar that you have submitted? Can I get a link?

Comment: Thanks for the info- this is very helpful.